# 7 day average in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to modify the following T-SQL statement to include a rolling 7 day average of the revenue.

What do I need to include in the following code to achieve that?

```
SELECT 
    CAST(create_dtg AS DATE) DATE, 
    SUM([agent_rev] + [anchor_rev] + [corp_rev] + [offsite_rev]) AS RevenueTotals, 
    SUM([media_est_cost] + [other_cost]) AS COSTTOTALS 
FROM   
    [dbo].[dw_rpt_traffic] 
WHERE  
    [create_dtg] >= ( Getdate() - 90 ) 
--GROUP BY CREATE_DTG 
--ORDER BY CREATE_DTG ASC
```

I also tried using Parttion by, however, this returns the same value as the Revenuetotals.

```
Select a.dte, a.revenuetotals, a.COSTTOTALS, AVG(A.RevenueTotals) OVER     (PARTITION BY a.dte ORDER BY a.dte ROWS 7 PRECEDING) as Day7Avg
from
(
   select CAST(CREATE_DTG AS DATE) as dte, 
          SUM([AGENT_REV]+[ANCHOR_REV]+[CORP_REV]+[OFFSITE_REV]) as RevenueTotals,
          SUM([MEDIA_EST_COST]+[OTHER_COST]) as COSTTOTALS
    FROM [dbo].[dw_rpt_traffic]
    where [CREATE_DTG] >= (GetDate() - 90)
    GROUP BY CREATE_DTG
    ) as A
 Group by a.dte, a.revenuetotals, a.COSTTOTALS
 order by a.dte
```

Thanks, Karen

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you looking for?

Comment: He is using SQL-Server (T-SQL). I fixed the question to be clearer and formmated the code to be readable. Should help now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rolling aggregates I typically use an `OVER` clause with `ROWS [...] PRECEDING [...]`.

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   x.Date
                       ,x.Revenue
                       ,AVG(x.Revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY x.Date 
                                              ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
                        ) AS [MA7]
               FROM     ( SELECT    CAST(t.Date AS DATE) AS [Date]
                                   ,SUM(t.Revenue) AS [Revenue]
                          FROM      #tmp t
                          WHERE     CAST(t.Date AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 96 AS DATE)
                          GROUP BY  CAST(t.Date AS DATE)
                        ) x
             )
    SELECT  c.Date
           ,c.Revenue
           ,c.MA7
    FROM    cte c
    WHERE   c.Date > CAST(GETDATE() - 90 AS DATE)
    ORDER BY c.Date;
```

---

The table above was generated with the following:

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE #tmp;
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
     [Date] DATETIME
    ,[Revenue] DECIMAL(18, 2)
    );
--
DECLARE @first INT = 0
   ,@last INT = 200;
WHILE @first < @last
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmp
                ( Date, Revenue )
        VALUES  ( GETDATE() - @first * 0.5, RAND() * 100000 );

        SET @first = @first + 1;
    END;
```

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this without creating temp table.  I currently do not have permissions to create and drop tables?

Comment: The temp table isn't necessary for the solution; I was just using it so that I could demonstrate the code on something concrete. You should be able to adapt your real table based on what is presented above. For example, `#tmp.Revenue` would be replaced by `[agent_rev] + [anchor_rev] + [corp_rev] + [offsite_rev]`, etc.

Comment: I need to include the CostTotals, and also calculate the Gross Profit(Revenue-costttotals)   how should this code be modified?

Comment: I am also confuse I do not see in reference to the actual data source, how are you bringing in the actual data?

Comment: The data source is the table `#tmp`, created in the second code passage, used *purely for demonstration purposes*. Do not get hung up on that. It was intended to be a simplification of the table described in your question. The technique presented in the first code passage should be *adapted* to suit the specific structure of your actual table; it will likely resemble what is [commented out  here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476870).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way uses `outer apply`:

```
with rt as (
       select CAST(CREATE_DTG AS DATE) as dte, 
              SUM([AGENT_REV]+[ANCHOR_REV]+[CORP_REV]+[OFFSITE_REV]) as RevenueTotals,
              SUM([MEDIA_EST_COST]+[OTHER_COST]) as COSTTOTALS
       from [dbo].[dw_rpt_traffic]
       where [CREATE_DTG] >= (GetDate() - 90)
      )
select rt.*, rolling.avgrt
from rt outer apply
     (select avg(rt2.RevenueTotals) as avgrt
      from rt rt2
      where rt2.dte >= dateadd(day, -6, rt.dte) and
            rt2.dte <= rt.dte
     ) rolling
order by dte;
```

Comment: I added the group by per the request of error message and it seems to hang

Comment: See modification to orignial post tried using partitions.